# Control log output in geb/cucumber/maven/selenium

Tags: maven, groovy, cucumber, geb

I have a gui test setup with this in the POM:

```
    <cucumber-jvm.version>1.1.5</cucumber-jvm.version>
    <cucumber-html.version>0.2.3</cucumber-html.version>
    <exec-maven-plugin.version>1.2.1</exec-maven-plugin.version>
    <gherkin.version>2.12.2</gherkin.version>
    <groovy.version>2.1.6</groovy.version>
    <junit.version>4.10</junit.version>
    <log4j.version>1.2.17</log4j.version>
    <maven-surefire-plugin.version>2.12.3</maven-surefire-plugin.version>
    <selenium-firefox-driver.version>2.40.0</selenium-firefox-driver.version>
    <geb.version>0.9.2</geb.version>
```

When I run the tests via "mvn test" in the command line, I get thousands (probably tens of thousands) of lines like this:

```
2016-03-24 12:04:20,157 DEBUG  wire -  >> "GET /session/5754abb30961963f03fb55f47dc26bb2/element/0.2653651861473918-605/text HTTP/1.1[\r][\n]"
2016-03-24 12:04:20,157 DEBUG  wire -  >> "Accept: application/json, image/png[\r][\n]"
2016-03-24 12:04:20,157 DEBUG  wire -  >> "Cache-Control: no-cache[\r][\n]"
2016-03-24 12:04:20,157 DEBUG  wire -  >> "Host: localhost:31037[\r][\n]"
2016-03-24 12:04:20,157 DEBUG  wire -  >> "Connection: Keep-Alive[\r][\n]"
2016-03-24 12:04:20,157 DEBUG  wire -  >> "[\r][\n]"
2016-03-24 12:04:20,282 DEBUG  wire -  << "HTTP/1.1 200 OK[\r][\n]"
2016-03-24 12:04:20,282 DEBUG  wire -  << "Content-Length:70[\r][\n]"
2016-03-24 12:04:20,282 DEBUG  wire -  << "Content-Type:application/json; charset=utf-8[\r][\n]"
2016-03-24 12:04:20,282 DEBUG  wire -  << "Connection:close[\r][\n]"
2016-03-24 12:04:20,283 DEBUG  wire -  << "[\r][\n]"
```

How do I control the debug level?  I don't even know what's producting this.

I've searched the source code of this inherited project and can find nothing.

I've searched the web for an answer, and also nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgrading the tooling didn't work because I started to get Java Stack Overflows.

I ended up adding these command line options to "mvn test"

```
-Dorg.apache.commons.logging.Log=org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SimpleLog
-Dorg.apache.commons.logging.simplelog.showdatetime=true
-Dorg.apache.commons.logging.simplelog.log.org.apache.http=INFO
-Dorg.apache.commons.logging.simplelog.log.org.apache.http.wire=ERROR
```

Answer (score 1):

It is http logging. I would search in or around Selenium for this.

My approach would be to update your tooling to newer versions. Some of the stuff you are using is a few years old.

Comment: Updating your dependencies will definitely be a good idea. The latest version of Geb is `0.13.1`, the latest version of groovy is `2.4.6`, the latest version of Selenium is `2.53.0`...